# Union Query taking hours to run

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have a UNION query that is combining about 28 queries. Is it normal for it to take hours? I can run them separately in about 20-30 min. Below is a snippet of my code. Sorry if its messy.

```
SELECT DISTINCT AP_CA_WM_Patrol.SID, [HR_Report].[Full_Nm]AS Name, 0 AS [Licensed and Registered (1= Yes; 0= No)], 0 AS [Antitrust (1= Yes; 0= No)], 0 AS [MFP (1= Yes; 0= No)], 0 AS [Doddfrank AP (1= Yes; 0= No)], 0 AS [FX_Trader (1= Yes; 0= No)], 0 AS [FX_Sales (1= Yes; 0= No)], 0 AS [OTA (1= Yes; 0= No)]
FROM AP_CA_WM_Patrol, HR_Report ,AM_L_R,AWM_L_R,APAC_L_R,EMEA_L_R,EMEA_L_R_Certified,LATAM_L_R,Antitrust,MFP,DoddFrank
WHERE (((AP_CA_WM_Patrol.SID)=[HR_Report].[Standard_Id]) AND ((AP_CA_WM_Patrol.[Business Level 1])="ASSET & WEALTH MANAGEMENT")
AND
((AP_CA_WM_Patrol.SID)<>[AM_L_R].[Username])
AND
((AP_CA_WM_Patrol.SID)<>[AWM_L_R].[id_sid])
AND
((AP_CA_WM_Patrol.SID)<>[APAC_L_R].[SID])
AND
((AP_CA_WM_Patrol.SID)<>[EMEA_L_R].[SID])
AND
((AP_CA_WM_Patrol.SID)<>[EMEA_L_R_Certified].[SID])
AND
((AP_CA_WM_Patrol.SID)<>[LATAM_L_R].[UNID])
AND
((AP_CA_WM_Patrol.SID)<>[Antitrust].[SIDs])
AND
((AP_CA_WM_Patrol.SID)<>[MFP].[SID])
AND
((AP_CA_WM_Patrol.SID)<>[Doddfrank].[SID]))


UNION

SELECT DISTINCT AP_CA_WM_SWAP.SID, [HR_Report].[Full_Nm]AS Name, 0 AS [Licensed and Registered (1= Yes; 0= No)], 0 AS [Antitrust (1= Yes; 0= No)], 0 AS [MFP (1= Yes; 0= No)], 0 AS [Doddfrank AP (1= Yes; 0= No)], 0 AS [FX_Trader (1= Yes; 0= No)], 0 AS [FX_Sales (1= Yes; 0= No)], 0 AS [OTA (1= Yes; 0= No)]
FROM AP_CA_WM_SWAP,HR_Report,AM_L_R,AWM_L_R,APAC_L_R,EMEA_L_R,EMEA_L_R_Certified,LATAM_L_R,Antitrust,MFP,DoddFrank 
WHERE (((AP_CA_WM_SWAP.SID)=[HR_Report].[Standard_Id]) AND ((AP_CA_WM_SWAP.[Business Level 1])="“Asset" & "Wealth Management”")
And
((AP_CA_WM_SWAP.SID)<>[AM_L_R].[Username])
AND
((AP_CA_WM_SWAP.SID)<>[AWM_L_R].[id_sid])
AND
((AP_CA_WM_SWAP.SID)<>[APAC_L_R].[SID])
AND
((AP_CA_WM_SWAP.SID)<>[EMEA_L_R].[SID])
AND
((AP_CA_WM_SWAP.SID)<>[EMEA_L_R_Certified].[SID])
AND
((AP_CA_WM_SWAP.SID)<>[LATAM_L_R].[UNID])
AND
((AP_CA_WM_SWAP.SID)<>[Antitrust].[SIDs])
AND
((AP_CA_WM_SWAP.SID)<>[MFP].[SID])
AND
((AP_CA_WM_SWAP.SID)<>[Doddfrank].[SID]))

UNION

SELECT DISTINCT APAC_L_R.SID, [HR_Report].[Full_Nm]AS Name, 1 AS [Licensed and Registered (1= Yes; 0= No)], 0 AS [Antitrust (1= Yes; 0= No)], 0 AS [MFP (1= Yes; 0= No)], 0 AS [Doddfrank AP (1= Yes; 0= No)], 0 AS [FX_Trader (1= Yes; 0= No)], 0 AS [FX_Sales (1= Yes; 0= No)], 0 AS [OTA (1= Yes; 0= No)]
FROM APAC_L_R, HR_Report
WHERE (((APAC_L_R.SID)=[HR_Report].[Standard_Id]));
```

Answer (score 1):

`union` needs to remove duplicates as it brings the result sets together. In general, it is not a good idea to use both `select distinct` and `union all`.

If the subqueries really are not returning duplicates, then replace `select distinct` with `select`.

If you don't expect duplicates between the subqueries, then change `union` to `union all`.

If you do both, then the query should return much faster.

Comment: Ill give it a try. I was able to run it before but i kept getting a bunch of duplicates which is why is did the select distinct.